# Need help passing timestamp to dictionary correctly

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, input, while-loop

I currently am trying to make a program which asks for input from the user, that is being stored to a dictionary and nested dictionary.

Everything is working fine, however one thing that is confusing me is creating a key which stores the datetime of when the dictionary was stored inside the while loop.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
user_list = {}
list_of_users = {}

while True: 

    print("Please enter your desired username below")
    username = input("What is your username? ")

    if username == 'print':
        break

    else:
        first = input("What is your first name? ")

        list_of_users.update({username : user_list})
        user_list['given name'] = first
        user_list['given name'] = username
        user_list['date'] = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(list_of_users)
```

Here is a sample output. As you can see the date value for the dictionary has the same exact times. I would like the time to be based on the time in which the data was stored in the while loop:

```
Please enter your desired username below
What is your username? monkey
What is your first name? john
Please enter your desired username below
What is your username? simon
What is your first name? whistler
Please enter your desired username below
What is your username? print
{'monkey': {'given name': 'simon', 'date': '2019-11-04 13:16:35'}, 'simon': {'given name': 'simon',     'date': '2019-11-04 13:16:35'}}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `now` separately in every iteration.
Right now you create the date object only at the beginning of your program, so it stays the same for the rest of the execution.

```
from datetime import datetime

user_list = {}
list_of_users = {}

while True: 

  print("Please enter your desired username below")
  username = input("What is your username? ")

  if username == 'print':
    break
  else:
    first = input("What is your first name? ")
    now = datetime.now()
    list_of_users.update({username : user_list})
    user_list['given name'] = first
    user_list['given name'] = username
    user_list['date'] = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    print(list_of_users)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for messaging me. I ran the code that you provided. In the first iteration, the time is correct. But if I enter more dictionary values after the first iteration, then the date values for both dictionary inputs are the same.

My intention is that the date values are unique per iteration, or dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized the variable *now* at the beginning of the code and are using it in the while loop.

If you want the correct output you need to remove

```
now = datetime.now()
```

And use

```
user_list['date'] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed the 'now = datetime.now()' from the beginning of the file, and now using only 'user_list['date'] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")' which is inside the loop, but in the else statement. I have the same issue with the other solution posted, if I run the iteration twice then the date values (more specifically the time) remains the same for both dictionary keys.